# Is there a technical term for sad songs with happy lyrics and vice versa?

Tags: terminology

I'm talking about things like the Pogues "Fairy Tale of New York", an upbeat song with bitter lyrics like

> Happy Christmas your arse / I pray God it's our last

Is there a technical term or collective name for songs where the emotion indicated by the music is at odds with the emotion indicated by the lyrics?

Comment: This might be better over on english.stackexchange.com Flagged for migration

Comment: I think this is on-topic but you would probably do well to ask it on English.  If you do, just let me know and we'll close this version.

Comment: Although it is English language, this is very specific to musical terms, and it is likely to be more experts on this here on Music than on English.

Answer (score 4):

Lyrical dissonance or agathocacological

Comment: Good answer.  A minor technical point on spelling - i.e., agathokakological .  I only know this because I had to look up the definition.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a term specific to the realm of music that I'm not aware of. Barring that, the first term that comes to mind is **incongruous**. It refers to a lack of consistency or harmony.

You could use the same word to describe a man wearing sweat pants to a black tie affair, or the sight of chicken fingers on a fancy French menu.

Comment: Les doigts de poulet!

Answer (score 2):

I think **ironic** would be appropriate; perhaps qualified "*musically* **ironic**"?

In standard music terminology, perhaps "scherzando" (It. *in a jesting manner*)?